# How to address ghost who moves runner (rug) constantly?

Tags: flooring

I have an old 1950s house which is apparently haunted by the original owner who passed away prior to my purchasing it. She likes to move the runner (thin rug) to either side of the hallway several times per day.

I recenter the rug at least 4x per day but I always find it completely pressed against either wall shortly after. I do not notice it moving off center when I walk on it.

Is there anyway to keep it in place? I know a relative who nailed their rug to the floor but I have new carpet and would prefer a less drastic solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Center runner
2. Point video recording device (camera, cell phone, etc.) at runner.
3. start recording.
4. review recording.

If cause proves to be supernatural, make lots of money selling the recording, buy a new house, problem solved. Perhaps open up the floor under the moving runner and see what's (or who's) buried there, etc. or sell the house as a real verified haunted house for an extra high price to someone who wants such a thing. Or open a haunted B&B...

Otherwise, double-sided carpet tape or various pointy things (such as mats with points to stick into the carpet and the runner.)